# Express.js get header in mddleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I create midleware for auth api key which is added to header.

```
const loger = require("easy-loger");

require('dotenv').config();
function authMiddleware(req, res, next){
    const appApiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
    let requestApiKey = req.headers.apikey;

    if(requestApiKey === "undefined"){
        loger.createLog('Try to authorize without api key from : '+ req.headers.host, 'info');
        res.status(401);
        res.json({
            code: 403,
            message: 'You need to authorize in this route'
        });
    }

    if(appApiKey === requestApiKey){
        next();
    }else {
        loger.createLog('Try to authorize user without rights with api key: '+ requestApiKey, 'info');
        res.status(403);
        res.json({
            code: 403,
            message: 'You have not permission for this route'
        });
    }
}
```

If i add this as a function in route evrything working OK but if i try to use this as a module u get error like this:

```
 let requestApiKey = req.headers.apikey;
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
```

How to get heders in export module mddleware?

Comment: can you post how you're using it in route and also the exported code part of `authMiddleware` module?

Comment: I use this middleware in file api.js
`var express = require('express');
var db = require('../modules/db/db');
var validator = require('validator');
var loger = require('easy-loger');
require('dotenv').config();
var auth = require('../modules/auth/authMiddleware');

var router = express.Router();
router.use(auth);
router.post ....
`
This api.js file is bind to app.js and without this middleware or if middleware is use as bind function `router.use(function authMiddleware(req, res, next) { ...` in api.js  app run corectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// in authMiddleware file you need to export the middleware
module.exports = { authMiddleware }

// in the file you use it, you need to :
const { authMiddleware } = require('../modules/auth/authMiddleware');
router.use(authMiddleware );
```

Comment: Thansk this option with export as object `module.exports = { authMiddleware }` run perfect.